# I want to use SQL in my app | Alamofire, Swift

Tags: iphone, database, swift, post, alamofire

I want to use a localhost database in SQL for my IOS's app, how can I use .POST in a specific table ?

PD: I use Alamofire in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire is a networking library and not related to the persistence layer.

iOS has the Core Data framework for database access, it can use an SQLite DB, XML, binary or in-memory persistent stores. You do not run SQL queries directly, you use predicates. I would suggest reading up on what options are available to you before you start.

Realm is a good library to use, from their website:

> Realm is a replacement for SQLite & Core Data

[Apple Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1)

[Realm Website](https://realm.io/)